# Mine monitor & simulation system

Tags: monitoring, simulation

We are looking for a software system that can help to monitor personnel/equipment in the mine and possible water breaking in the mine. We want this system can run on our 3-d data collect/analyse/visualize platform. The budget is about 20k USD.

We hope that this system can track the position where the water break in, the speed/type of the water and to predict the best evacuation path for the workers in the mine when it happens.

Also, we want this system can simulate possible water breaking into mine, so we can practice evacuation base on the data its' simulation.

So this system has two main purposes:

1. monitor and collect data in mine;
2. simulate the possible water breaking for us to practice evacuation.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Do you ***only** want simulation? Or do you also want a working system? I am thinking that this will have to be custom made

Comment: Welcome. Which operating system? [tag:gratis], or do you have a budget? please read [ask]. The more information that you give us, the more that we can help you.

Comment: " We want this system can run on our 3-d data collect/analyse/visualize platform - then, obviously, you will have to give some details of this system. Is it in-house developed, or did you buy it from someone. Do you need new hardware to do the monitoring (which your budget does not cover) or will your existing h/w do that (if so, please give details).

Comment: No offence intended, this is not aimed at you, but I hope that you can learn from it. I started a s/w company in Asia and abandoned it after a few years. Customers with only a warm, fuzzy feeling of what they wanted. Agreeing a ridiculously low price and adding features as they thought of them, with no increased budget. Please, don't be that customer. If you are, it won't end well for you either.

Comment: For US $5k, I would agree to discuss with you and specify the system in detail. That's what a week or two of my time is worth. Development cost would be six figures for software, plus hardware costs. A mine, I would think, makes millions. Don't be ridiculous in your budget.  Until we know if you use commercial software or in-house, and if have existing sensors, we can't way more. But it is highly unlikely that you will find off the shelf software to handle both your existing software an sensors.

Comment: Expect to pay for development of custom s/w, maybe with new h/w. And don't expect it to be cheap. You will get what you pay for,and do not try to save money on a system which could save or costs lives. You might end up paying more in lawsuits.

Comment: While it was nice of community to bump this to bump this to the front page, I have been in private contact with the OP and the project has been cancelled.

Comment: Which didn't prevent it from being bumped again ;-) NVM, it's an interesting topic & I look forward to other answers.

Comment: If I were doing this today, I would use cheap but powerful ESP32 boards. For US $7 or less, you get BlueTooth and WiFi, plus GPIO pins. I would use battery powered BLE wearables for the employees.  There was recent posting on our Internet of Things sister sire enitled [What are the sensors available to measure liquid levels?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/4319/what-are-the-sensors-available-to-measure-liquid-levels). It is also easy and cheap to measure temperature, humidity, air pressure, air pollution & more --->

Comment: ---> I know from privately emailing the OP that the project was cancelled, but add this here in case anyone is considering something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that you will not find anything mine specific.

All that I can find (for free) is the [ZET evacuation tool](http://zet-evakuierung.de/en/index.html), but it seems like it meets your needs (so long as we think of a mine as an upside down building :-)

> The ZET softwaretools, which is licensed under the GPL. allows to
>   model evacuation scenarios and simulate and optimze them. Within ZET
>   multi-storey buildings can be designed and residents can be placed and
>   emergency exits can be assigned to them.
>
> An earliest arrival flow is then computed to route the residents to
>   the best exits. Since the flow computation has to make certain
>   idealistic assumptions, the included simulation can then be used to
>   test the computed evacuation paths. A wide selection of statistics and
>   an advanced visualizer help to analyze the data

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: thank you for your time. let me edit the main question to be more specific.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. And no, I am not that customer. I don't own a mine just working for someone else. my job is to looking for a system I mentioned in the post for our client which is a university in Asia and their budget for this is about 20k USD. I am not the one to decide the budget. I did some research but didn't find any fit the requirement. That's why I post in this newly found website. My apologies for not providing more information at first.

Comment: So there is no way to get a system like that with such a low budget? I don't know much about the market price, if so, I will let them know. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for not being offended. I really am only trying to help. Key points to mention to them – 

1) they have an existing system. Find out as much about it as you can. Only then can you specify the new project. If it is  in-house developed, there is zero chance of an off the shelf s/w interfacing with it, without some change.

Comment: 2) Do they have existing h/w which can make the measurements that they want? If so, do they already collect data, or do they need new s/w for hat?  If not, figure out how many places they want to monitor, find a sensor & calculate the cost. Also, wifi in a mine will mean many repeaters, but the alternative is wire. That’s within the mine – how to get the data up the shaft?

Comment: 3) For such a custom project it is most likely that you need a custom solution, not off the shelf.  You *might* hope to string together some FOSS, though, such as ZET, or modify it (the GPL, which ZET uses, says that if you modify the code, you have to make it publicly available)

Comment: 4) I would offer to help in detail, but bitter experience in Asia shows that I will put in weeks or months unpaid and produce a detailed plan/report, only to have them thank me for the report and say that they are not interested. Who knows what happens to the  report afterward?

5) My advice is to buy a single sensor & assign some comp sic students to do parts of it as their coursework.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I will contact them and ask for those information and see if we can get some CS students. but it may take some time for them to response since they are in spring festival holidays. Thanks again for your help. it really helps a lot.

Comment: Oops, I forgot about Lunar New Year.  I won't post my email address here, but if you get a throwaway address & post it, I will contact you & give what advice I can. Or, we cna just move to the chat room here.

Comment: Ok, Lei Sun, I will write to you now. Best delete your email from here.